# Horror film about a man brought out of cryogenic suspension without a soul, around 1990

Tags: story-identification, movie, cryogenics

This is a matter of vague childhood memories, but I remember seeing a preview for a film on TV where a man was brought out of cryogenic suspension and somehow, the process had made him a killer. I want to say that the preview stated that he'd come back without a soul. I suspect it was around 1990 because I remember seeing what I thought was the preview again, but instead, it was for *Child's Play 3*, showing Chucky being remade out of the melted plastic from the prior film.

As for actual imagery of the preview, I don't recall a ton. I remember a scene of the killer being decanted from suspension, complete with billowing liquid nitrogen fog, and a later scene showing him being introduced at a party. It didn't seem futuristic in tone, probably set in the then present day.

I'm 99% certain it's not *Demolition Man*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could it be Wes Craven's *[Chiller](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088912/)*?

Synopsis:
Corporate exec Miles Creighton dies, and is cryogenically frozen in the hopes that he can be revived. 10 years later, the procedure is a success, and Miles returns--without his soul.

Comment: That's too close of a match to be coincidence. Huh. I guess they must have been previewing a reshow. Either that, or my brain is conflating two different movie teasers...